# Chromatic filter openCV

Tags: opencv, filter

I'm looking for a filter in openCV library that change the image chromatically. For example, the blur does not change the colors of the image, I need one that do it.

I got a colored image, I need to apply a filter that distorts the color. For example, if I have an image with a lot of blue, with this filter this blue will be less or more intensity.

My images are in L* a* b* colour space and I need to work in it.

Comment: Please be more specific/precise about your goals and show what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Added more explanation, I have not found anything to do that...

Comment: Look here at HSL and consider selecting blues and increasing saturation... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183666/2836621

Comment: I need to work in L*a*b* color space, there is not a filter such as blur that change colors? And I need to do that with various intensities.

Comment: If you already know you need to work in **Lab** colourspace you are clearly able to improve the quality of your question... so that would be a good place to start getting help.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question.

Comment: It's not really a filter that you need. You just need to apply a function that decreases the **a** and/or increases the **b** if you want to decrease the blue component.