# How to increment yellow pixels in RGB image

Tags: opencv

I have an image stored in RGB color space and I need to detect yellow pixel and increment each one by 5. 
For example, if I have a photo with a yellow lemon and a brown table, I have to turn the lemon more yellow and the table must remain the same. 
Then I have to save the new image.

How can I perform it with openCV and C++?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183666/2836621

Comment: Another example to find color in HSV: [how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

1. Convert image into HSV color space.
2. Calculate yellow range in HSV (from Scalar to Scalar).
3. Create binary mask for yellow: inRange.
4. Call add with mask from (3) for your HSV image and cv::Scalar(5, 0, 0)
5. Convert Result to RGB.

Example:

```
cv::Mat rgbImg = cv::imread("src.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Mat hsvImg;
cv::cvtColor(rgbImg, hsvImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
cv::Mat threshImg;
cv::inRange(hsvImg, cv::Scalar(20, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(30, 255, 255), threshImg);
cv::imwrite("thresh.png", threshImg);
cv::add(hsvImg, cv::Scalar(5, 0, 0), hsvImg, threshImg);
cv::cvtColor(hsvImg, rgbImg, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);
cv::imwrite("res.png", rgbImg);
```

And pictures:
[image: Source image:]
[image: Binary mask:]
[image: Result:]

Comment: Nice answer, but I would recommend to avoid deprecated C API (cvAddS) and use C++ (cv::add)

Comment: Can you make an example with c++?

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution!

Comment: @Davide577 if this person's solution solved your problem, consider marking this as the accepted answer :)